# Grails fails to recognize Java class

Tags: grails

I'm using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0 on Windows 7(32 bit).  I cannot for the life of me get Grails to recognize a simple Java class I created in the /src/java directory of my Grails application.

Here is my java class:

```
public class PleaseWork {

    public static void hello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from a java class.");
    }
}
```

I am calling the java class from a service I created:

```
package mypackage
class CreatePdfService {

    def serviceMethod() {

        PleaseWork.hello()
    }
}
```

I've checked my .classpath for my project and I see the following:

```
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/groovy"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="grails-app/conf"/>....
```

It looks like my java source directory is included and there are no settings that are excluding it.  Everything looks good.

My understanding is that I should be able to call that java class with no problem.  And I can do a grails run-app with no issues.  But... when I run my application and the code attempts to call PleaseWork.hello() I get the following:

```
| Error 2013-02-18 15:59:10,898 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -   
MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] /mypackage/main/createPdf
No such property: PleaseWork for class: mypackage.CreatePdfService. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: PleaseWork for class: mypackage.CreatePdfService
```

I've done grails refresh-dependencies and nothing works.  What gives?

Comment: I just figured it out:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access classes from the "default" package from a class in a package. Either move the class to the same package as the service, or put it in a different one and add an import.

Comment: If I want to put my java class in another package, where I am able to?

Comment: Any valid package you want - just add an import as needed where you reference it

Comment: I tryed to create a java folder under src folder, but compiler doesnt recognize any class or package there. Placing it under services folder works.

Comment: You should be able to put Java files under src/groovy. Are you using IntelliJ? If there's no src/java folder and you manually add it, it's not automatically considered a source folder, you need to right-click it and choose "Mark directory as > Sources Root"

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and I created the folder manually but I understand where is the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Ah...  Thank you Bert.  I did the following....

I created a package within that /src/java folder.  I called the package "this.works"

Here is my updated Java class:

```
package this.works;

public class PleaseWork 
{

    public static void hello()
    {
       System.out.println("Hello from a java class.");
    }
}
```

Here is my updated Groovy class that is calling the Java class:

```
package myPackage

import this.works.PleaseWork

class CreatePdfService {

   def serviceMethod() {
         PleaseWork.hello()
   }
}
```

This now works.  I can do a grails run-app and my method in my Java class is called.