# How to run java programs in grails?

Tags: java, grails

I wrote a simple java program Hello.java, it looks like:

```
 public class Hello {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello ...");
     }
 }
```

I wanna it run under grails, so I created an app "hello", and put Hello.java under src/java, then run grails run-app, but when I click the "hello.HelloController" from `http://localhost:8080/hello/`, it shows the following errors:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI:/hello/hello/index  
Class:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException 
Message:No such property: Hello for class: hello.HelloController
```

The content of HelloController.groovy is:

```
class HelloController {

    def index() {
        Hello.main(null)
    }
}
```

Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your Hello file in a package

so inside src/java

create  a folder/package called test

put Hello inside test

```
import test.Hello

class HelloController {

    def index() {
        Hello.main(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, The reason is: You can't access classes from the "default" package from a class in a package.

following is another similar subject:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947488/grails-fails-to-recognize-java-class

Answer (score 0):

You have to import class `Hello`:

```
import Hello

class HelloController {

    def index() {
        Hello.main(null)
    }
}
```

See Java docs about packages and `import` statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: Thanks, but the same error occurs.
And if I add "package hello" at the top of HelloController.groovy, it will get another error "HelloController.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class Hello" @line3 column1 (import Hello)

Answer (score 0):

Running `grails clean`, followed by `grails compile` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In grails 3, you have to put your java classes inside src/main/groovy.

create a package called "test" inside src/main/groovy

```
package test
public class Hello {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello ...");
     }
 }
```

and import the package in HelloController

```
import test.Hello

class HelloController {

    def index() {
        Hello.main(null)
    }
}
```

This will work.